# is there an "inverse" function to IN() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, arrays

The scenario is this: in a table A, I have one column "tags", which is varchar(255).
In this column I store numbers, separated by commas, like this:

`2,14,31,33,56`

etc. there can be none, one, or several.

and I need to make a SELECT query that will return rows that have a certain number in this field. right now I'm using this method (don't be alarmed, I know its a poor way.. that's why I'm asking for help!). for example, let's assume the number I want to check is 33. the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE
tags LIKE "%,33,%" OR tags LIKE "33,%" OR tags LIKE "%,33" OR tags LIKE "33"
```

I'm no expert but I know this can't be the method. The first question that comes to mind is: is there a command similar to `IN()` but that works the other way around?

I mean, can I tell it "find rows where 'tags' contains value 33" ?

When asking this question, I can see that there may be another field type other than varchar(255) to contain this type of data (an array of numbers, after all)

Is there a GOOD and efficient way of doing this? my method works for small tables, yes, but if the table grows.. (say, 10k rows, 50k, 300k ... ) this is obviously a problem.

Comment: What you are running into is why you should normalize your data, instead of storing a list in a single column. This problem is bad with a handful of values and terrible when you reach any sort of scale.

Answer (score 2):

The function that you want is `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
WHERE find_in_set(33, tags) > 0;
```

You can simplify your `like` statement to be:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
WHERE concat(',', tags, ',') LIKE '%,33,%';
```

Neither of these can make use of an index.  Having a separate table with one row per entity and per tag is the right way to go (but I think you know this already).

Comment: thanks for such speedy response. I will try that. however, as you mention, this cannot make use of an index (which is what I really want.. because I need this to be fast). Yes, I know that the other way to is a new table, which cross-references both things (a table with columns tag_id, and reference_id of example, with both columns indexed). the thing is that, if my current table_a tan reach, say, 300k rows, imagine that each one will have 10 tags in average.. that would give me a cross-ref table of 3 million rows... I don't like, it smells like problem...

Comment: in other words: there isn't another field type (not varchar) that would allow for an array of ids, and somehow indexed... is there? am I asking for too much? ;) thanks!

Comment: @user3478061 . . . You need to store the data in the proper format using an association/junction table if you want to use indexes.